# Locking mouse events in cappuccino web application

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cappuccino

While developing a web-application based on the cappuccino-framework which
only has to run in a Chromium browser environment (~ Chromium V.19 released spring this year)
I struggle with the following problem:

We want the application to lock or delete all mouse clicks for some seconds (while the application performs some background calculations).

This apparently simple task seems to be almost impossible.
we implemented a `Html-<div>` layer over the whole screen and tried to manipulate its
mouseup, mousedown-handlers like:

> onmouseup="return false;"
>
> onmousedown="return false;"

but that didn't show any results.

Also iterating through all CPControl subviews of the actual Cappuccino window-view
and disable them

> [subview setEnabled:NO];

does not really help:

Then indeed the subviews become disabled (and can't be clicked, exactly what we want)
but too LATE: although we disabled them BEFORE starting the background task,
the disable-effect comes into effect AFTER the background task has finished and so does
not prevent the user from making silly clicks during a sensible calculation.

I also tried to implement code like

> [CPRunLoop limitDateForMode:CPDefaultRunLoopMode];

after disabling the CPControls and before starting the background task but it also does not work.

So has anyone an idea either on the Javascript-/Html or Cappuccino side?

Answer (score 1):

CPWindow has a method: setIgnoresMouseEvents: Just call that on your window.

Comment: thanks for the tipp. Unfortunately we have exactly the same kind

Comment: thanks for the tip. After implementing it unfortunately we have exactly the same kind of problems we had, when we disabled every single CPControl as described above: The window locks mouse events AFTER performing the background task. Also 

[CPRunLoop limitDateForMode:CPDefaultRunLoopMode];

does not help. (Btw. I have no clear understanding what exactly this methods does or how in general Cappucc. implements "runloops" (which are an Objective-C but not javascript concept - is there any explanation for that available?). Has anyone an idea or help for the "timing problem" described above? thx.

Comment: So, first off, what do you mean by a "background task"?

I don't think you're talking about a web worker (which is a true "background task"), so I'm left to conclude you mean an operation that takes a long time to execute. 

So your issue is that while it's executing the user can just click around and the browser will queue up the events for the next (javascript) runloop.

Also, Javascript does have a runloop… it's not specific to Objective-C. That said, Cappuccino also has its own runloop.

Comment: You're right, with "background task" I mean a long lasting (~3s) operation NOT a web worker. Thanks for the hint of JS-runloop. But how can I tell Cappuc. to let the disable effects described above come into effect BEFORE that sort of background task starts, this is my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, now I could manage the timing problem in that way, that I set the ignoresMouseEvents-flag and  then put the "background task" code into a function f, set as input-parameter for a windows.setTimeout(f,1). Now the disabling-effect occurs BEFORE the background task starts, exactly what we want! But another problem arises: after setting this flag again to false it comes out that the clicks during the disable stage are NOT really ignored! They seem to be stored in some kind of queue and are now performed! This we definitely don't want! How can we clear that 'queue'? Thanks for any idea.